# Remove "name of chapter" in the chapter but keeping the table-of-contents entrance

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I made a book, kind of diccionary, about a subject. For the table-of-contents  I am using the star-version `\chapter*{nameofchapter}`, so I would like to remove "nameofchapter" from the first page of each chapter but, generating an entrance in the table-of-contents. My code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,newtxtext,newtxmath,multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex,mathabx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=,linkcolor=darkblue2}
\pagecolor{white}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphics}
%
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}
\def\sr{\specialrule{.7pt}{0pt}{0pt}}
\def\di{$\diamond$}
\newcommand{\np}[1]{$^\mathbf{#1}$}
%
\definecolor{lilita}    {RGB}{215,205,247}
\definecolor{darkblue2} {rgb}{0,0,0.7}
%
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=2]{portadas}
\pagecolor{lilita}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[pages=4]{portadas}
\include{i}
\includepdf[pages=5]{portadas}
\include{u}
\end{document}
```

that produces: [MWE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aujkY_vEndxUG1fnhFmALBr6plO_rUO9). So in this MWE what I would like is to "remove" the 'I' in p5, and the 'U' in p7, but keeping the hyperlinks in the table of contents. In file 'i.tex' I'm using:

```
\chapter*{I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{I}
```

and the same in file 'u.tex'. The file 'portadas.pdf': [portadas](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LKljeDD-yEDmEeMIk1yWm1n8GNwd21J8). 
Also, if it is possible, how do I change the color of "Índice General" to my 'darkblue2' color?

Comment: You can use `\addcontentsline` without `\chapter` if you don't want the chapters to be marked as such in the body text. Also, this MWE isn't actually minimal: it requires loading a bunch of packages that have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Very cool artwork!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use `\chapter*` directives in `i.tex`, `u.tex`, etc. Instead, write something such as

  ```
  % i.tex  %% loaded via an \include statement
  %\chapter*{I} % <-- no longer needed
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{I}

  Chapter I material ...
  ```
- Regarding the appearance of the table of contents: Since you also have `\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue2}`, setting the page color of the Table of Contents page to `darkblue` as well will make toc entries literally invisible. Not the intended effect, I assume. So, either choose a different page color or a different link color. To change the page color on the ToC page, you could replace the directive `\tableofcontents` with

  ```
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagecolor{yellow} % or whatever color is deemed appropriate
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
  ```
- In addition, you should probably either run `\pagestyle{plain}` in the preamble or do something more with the running headers.

Aside: I had to comment out the instruction that loads the `mathabx` package in order to avoid getting a whole bunch of warning messages. Do you really need this package? If so, load it at an earlier stage in the preamble.

Comment: I thank you for your answer.  I did what you suggested, but now I have "Índice General" on every page. (By the way, this is the phrase I would like to be blue, not the page.)  What can I do?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz - Did you include the instruction `\pagestyle{plain}`, as I suggested? That should suppress the running headers. (If placing this instruction in the preamble doesn't work, try placing it immediately after `\begin{document}`.) To get "Índice General" to be typeset in `darkblue2`, I suggest you load the `sectsty` package and run the instruction `\chapterfont{\color{darkblue2}}`.

Comment: Works wonderfully! Can you help me put the page numbers also in darkblue2? Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz - I suppose you could give `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\textcolor{darkblue2}{\arabic{page}}` a try.

Comment: It's working!  I thank you so much for your advice. Cheers!  :)

Comment: Hi Mico, can you have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433903/chapters-first-page-include-in-tableofcontents) as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks. I've left a comment below the [posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433903/5001). Let's see how (and if...) the OP responds.

Comment: I deleted the post 'cause it is answered here. Thank you :-)